# C++ : Transfer the Program into Header

Tags: c++, class, object, header, program-entry-point

Im new in C++, and i got a program called sendSMS:

```
#include "ServerSocket.h"
#include "SocketException.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Socket.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Config.h"
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <SerialStream.h>

void *func_servidor(void *ptr_timer);

ServerSocket server(30001);

pthread_t thread_servidor;
pthread_t thread_transfdados;
pthread_t thread_BD;

pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_mutex_t mp;

int ret;


#define CTRL_C "\x1A"

const int PORT_MON = 30000;

const string serialPort = "/dev/ttyS0";


using namespace LibSerial;
using namespace std;


int setSerial(SerialStream& ssStream, const string& port) {
...
....
}

int sendsms(int argc, char **argv) {
bool send = true;
...
....
return(0);
}

void *func_servidor(void *ptr)
{
...
....
return(0);
}
```

I want to transfer all those functions to a header .h file and call it in a main program(main.cpp), so the main.cpp only calls "everything" like:

```
#include sendSMS.h

class modem{
{
     public:
       void SendSms();
}

int main{
  SendSms();
  return(0);
}
```

And the header will be like?

```
#ifndef __SENDSMS__ 
#define __SENDSMS__ 

#include "ServerSocket.h"
#include "SocketException.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Socket.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Config.h"
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <SerialStream.h>

class sendsms
{
    private:
    int ret;
    const int PORT_MON;
    int argc;
    const string serialPort;
    char **argv;
    bool send;

    public:
    sendsms();
    void *func_servidor(void *ptr);
    int setSerial(SerialStream& ssStream, const string& port);
    int  sendsms();

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.cpp you will need an object of type `modem` in order to call `sendsms()` from `main()`:

```
#include sendSMS.h

class modem{
{
     public:
       void SendSms();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    modem m;
    m.SendSms();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thx, but i dont know how to turn that sendSMS.cpp into sendSMS.h

Comment: You should put the definitions into sendSMS.h, then the implementation of that into sendSMS.cpp. When you `#include sendSMS.h` in your main.cpp you will be able to call the methods as i posted above.

Comment: Yeah, thx..I dont know almost nothing about class and objects...I will update my question trying to create the sendSMS.h